# Is there a way to list which functions have changed between two executable binaries?

Tags: c++, diff, executable

***The TLDR/summary***:  Is there a way, given two executable files (both compiled from C++, with debug-info present, and from identical or near-identical source code) to list out only the functions that are different in one, relative to the other?

***The background/motivation***:  At the end of every sprint, our engineering team hands a "hero" build over to our QA team as a release candidate.  The SQA team then spends several man-weeks testing the release candidate to make sure it works correctly.  (They've automated as much of the testing as they can, but there are some parts that aren't easy to automate, hence the laborious manual testing/verification).  Inevitably, they come across one or more faults in the release candidate, at which point a bug report is filed, and engineering fixes the bugs and generates a new release-candidate.

At this point, the SQA team has to make a decision:  do they restart all testing from scratch, or do they assume that the new release-candidate is identical to the previous release-candidate except for the requested fixes -- i.e. that no regressions were introduced in other parts of the program?

The first choice ("restart from scratch") is safer, but expensive, and causes significant schedule-slippage.  The second choice ("just continue testing as before, but with the new build") is quicker, but risks having regressions slip through to the user, if any newly-introduced faults appear in parts of the program that had already been tested using the old build.

So when SQA asks me for advice on this decision, I currently do an "svn diff" between the two build-dates to check exactly what C++ code changed between the two builds, and use that to estimate the risk level of not doing a full-retest.  However, some of our SQA people don't trust our build process as much as I do, and they are reluctant to make the assumption that just because the source code has barely changed, that means the executable has barely changed.  (i.e. they say "but what if some setting has been changed on the build machine that we don't know about?"; to which I can only appeal to their faith in humanity that nobody would do such a thing)

Therefore, to assuage SQA's fears (and my own), it would be very useful if I could take the new release-candidate executable and do a "diff" on it (vs the old/partially-tested release-candidate executable) and see exactly which functions are different and which remain unchanged.  (Obviously I could just use binary-diff or MD5 checksums to do this, but those will only tell me that the two executables are different; they won't tell me which functions are different, which is what I really want to know -- e.g. that after I fixed a typo in the About-box, the core-business-logic functions in the executable didn't change relative to was tested earlier)

I realize the answer to this is likely OS-specific; however we compile under Linux, MacOS/X, and Linux, so any insight for any of those three OS's would be welcome.

Comment: The way to see how the old and new differ is via a diff of the source code. Sounds like you need to spend some time educating your SQA staff. A diff on the executable code is only going to show binary differences; there's no way to see what functionality changed. The linker can rearrange the binary content in many different ways (for instance, incremental builds will use some padding to allow minor changes to occur without having to rebuild the entire binary content).

Comment: A tool like svn seems to be helpful to track the changes.

Comment: @KenWhite Our build machine always builds from scratch.  I'm not trying to see what functionality changed, but since e.g. `nm` can list the names and addresses of all symbols, it stands to reason that there ought to be a way to list e.g. the sizes of the symbols or perhaps a checksum of each symbol's contents as well; then I could use that data to see which symbols have changed and which have not.  (and if it shows that many or all of them have changed due to the linker's creativity, so be it; at least I'll have learned something about linkers :) )

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ svn is very helpful for tracking changes in the source code, and I use that regularly; however what I'm looking for is a way to track changes in the resulting executables instead.

Comment: My point was that a difference in the binary executable isn't going to show you anything useful. You could use the linker's map file to look at sizes and changes in addresses, for instance, but it's going to show you much less than an svn diff of the source code, and what it does reveal won't be of any use to SQA staff who don't understand source code changes and their effects. I think you're barking up the wrong tree here.

Comment: Mainly what I'm trying to do is verify that things *haven't* changed.  As far as operating at the source-code level, I 90% agree with that and that is my usual routine -- but when SQA questions the reliability of the source->executable transform, I'd like to have a better counter-argument than "you just have to trust the compiler to be consistent", since even to me that feels like a leap of faith.

Comment: Do you realize what you are being told to do? You are essentially required to produce a zero-knowledge proof that the code you wrote will pass the tests that have not run yet. Think about that for a minute. When you solve this problem just know you have solved a class of problems known as "intractability". Tell your SQA team to write their damn tests and if it fails, they should fix the tests until it doesn't fail anymore.

Comment: In all seriousness, this is a problem that should be solved by testing, not by diffing binaries. You are only digging trenches around the problem if you proceed in this manner. Your team needs a new approach to testing and no amount of binary diffs will ever compensate for a proper approach to testing your code

Comment: @smac89 I'm not being "told to do" anything; this is a problem I'm taking on for myself -- i.e. it is a way for me to check whether my changes to the source code resulted in only the changes to the binary I expected, or if other (unrelated, possibly unwanted) changes have crept in as well.  Currently I can only *assume* that the new executable contains only my intended changes and nothing more; if I succeed, I will be able to verify that that is in fact the case.   (As for a new approach to testing, that would be great, but sometimes it's just not possible)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this question appears to be that no, there do not exist any such tools (at least, not outside the anti-malware community).

Therefore, just to see if it could be done, I wrote a simple proof-of-concept [executable_diff](https://github.com/jfriesne/executable_diff) utility that does more or less what I was looking for.  It runs under Linux and MacOS/X, and when invoked it runs each of the two executables through a disassembler ("otool" under MacOS/X, "objdump" under Linux), then scans the disassembly text to see which functions in the text-segment (or strings in the .rodata segment) are different between one executable and the next.

It then prints out a list of which functions are not identical to their counterpart in the other executable, and also write out a file containing the actual diffs in case the user would like to see *how* the functions are different.

The main complicating factor in implementing this program was that when you change the size of one function in the program, that change ripples through the rest of the program since all of the addresses of functions that come later in the text-segment change as well.  Therefore the program also contains logic to filter out false-positives (by converting absolute addresses in the assembly back into their corresponding function names before doing the diff)

As the commenters on this question have noted, diffing executables is no substitute for using version control and keeping track of the repository-revision-number associated with each built executable, so that you can do your diffs at the source code level instead.  I wrote this only to see if it could be done, and as a learning exercise to teach myself more about how changes to source code are reflected in the resulting binaries.  executable_diff should be considered a rough heuristic only, as it will no doubt produce false-positives in some cases and erroneously ignore meaningful changes in others.